# Undefined relationship on Model when upgrade and run unit test in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

After upgrade Laravel from 5.5 to 5.6 and running test, in file laravel.log: Call to undefined relationship [user] on model [Rate]. I think the fault lies here. But i don't fix

```
  $rateable->user->notify($notification);
```

Comment: Can you show us the Rate model, specifically the user() function?

Comment: before upgrade, i run test and it's works. and i don't understand. This is my relation of Rate model: ```public function rateable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }``` And model Rateable: ```public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }```